# Socket + python как сделать чтобы сразу несколько пользователей поключались к серверу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, сервер, сокет

хотел попробовать создать сервер но наткнуля на ошибку что если подключается больше 1 человека то выдает ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "host.py", line 20, in 
data = conn.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом

вот мой код:
host.py

```
import socket
import random


sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print ('connected:', addr)

f = open('host_base.txt')
for line in f:
    line
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(addr))
key = random.randint(1000, 9999)
print(key)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.sendall(bytes(str(key),'UTF-8'))
    conn.sendall(data.upper())
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее Вам нужен не блокирующий сокет. Посмотрите примеры с setblocking().
Один из шаблонов из моих заметок:

```py
import socket
import time

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind(("", 8001))
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,
                    1)
    sock.listen(5)  
    sock.setblocking(False)  # Не блокирующий режим,
    # при отсутвии клиента работа продолжается и вызывается исключение нет данных

    while True:
        try:
            client, addr = sock.accept()
            client.setblocking(False)
        except socket.error:
            print(">>> CLIENT NOT FOUND!")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("ERR")
            sock.close()
            break
        else:
            result = client.recv(1024)
            client.send(b"Done!")
            client.close()
            print("Message: ", result.decode("utf-8"), addr)
        time.sleep(1)  # Проверять каждую секунду можно УДАЛИТЬ!
```

Comment: спасибо! Очень долго искал